# Receiving 500 internal server error installing WordPress on IIS 7 at GoDaddy

Tags: iis-7, wordpress, 500-error

I have a virtual shared hosting plan on GoDaddy.

I am trying to set up WordPress on it. However, whenever I run `/wp-admin/install.php` I receive an `internal 500 error`.

What would cause this? I'm totally lost. I didn't think this would be difficult to get set up.

Comment: Is this really sysadmin? (A personal website trying to run wordpress?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and  managed to view the details of the error (Error 500) by making some changes at the web.config file. Check the link below for more information.

[How to show the details of Error 500 on Web Server.](http://jeeshenlee.wordpress.com/2010/10/27/how-to-show-the-details-of-error-500-on-web-server/)

Tested it on GoDaddy and it's working. :)

Comment: Broken link. This is why answers should include the solution itself and not just a link to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress works fine on Godaddy with Windows hosting running IIS 7.  Don't let anybody tell you it will only work on Linux.

Check these issues in your Hosting Control Center at Godaddy:

1. Verify you are running IIS 7.  You probably wont get it to run on IIS 6.
2. Verify that your install folder is set as Application Root and "anonymous access" is checked.
3. In Hosting Control Center > Content > File Manager, select your install folder, click on "Permissions" and uncheck Inherit.  Then check "Read", "Write" and "Reset all children to inherit".
4. In Content > IIS Management, select the Content Root folder and then click "Advanced".  Make sure pipeline mode is set to 'Integrated".
5. In Content > Add On Languages, verify you are are running .Net Runtime 2.0/3/0/3.5 and PHP 5.x.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem..the problem was that there was no config file, (wp-config.php) I remote desktop to the server to see the error and word press showed me a screen telling me. Then it had a button saying create config file..and it worked.

I am lucky becuase I have a dedicated server so I could remote desktop to the site. If you are using shared hosting what you need to do is find away of showing the error, and you will be fine.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the above checks!

Make sure your use the correct path to installer file; i.e. http://localhost:port/wp-admin/install.php

where port is the number of port if you are hosting multiple sites on IIS

Answer (score 0):

I would cancel the account, call up HostMonster (its only 5.95 a month with unlimited access) and they have a "Simple Scripts" control panel that sets up Wordpress for you and you dont need to do a thing.

Comment: THe problem is, I have other sites on the account. Essentially, this is a freebie this way.

Comment: What's your time worth?  Let me know when it reaches $72 and I'll show you how to get a YEAR'S worth of hosting cheap. ;-)

Comment: $72? 28 minutes and 48 seconds. Except we bill in 30 minute increments, so let's make it an even $75 for 30.

Comment: EXACTLY.  Some problems are easiest (and best) solved with a credit card.  Time is something you can never get back. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possible causes for that error. The best thing to do is look at the server logs for more specific information about the error. Contact GoDaddy support for assistance.

Here are a couple of links that may be of some help:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/259015

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/279689

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem is web.config is re-written incorrectly by wpmu creating dupes rewrite rules. If you remove these, all is fine

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been a while but I just came across the same error.  I am not on GoDaddy but I want to post this somewhere so others can find it.

I fixed this easily by updating the Error Pages within the specific website.  Edit the 500 error message, and point it to /index.php.  This worked for me.  Am not sure about a GoDaddy set up, but it seems a default IIS install error configuration doesn't like WordPress when view remotely.

Read more if you want: http://you.arenot.me/2013/01/31/wordpress-new-install-on-windows-iis-7-with-500-internal-server-error/

And I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

There are several factors to occur this issue on Wordpress with GoDaddy. If you are a tech guy you first need to check logs that where the problem occurs.

try some of the basic techniques to resolve this issue such as clear browser cache, changes web browser, increase PHP limit & review you .htaccess file.

Or you can try some of the below references that may help you to resolve this issue

[Troubleshoot a WordPress internal server error](https://godaddy.com/help/troubleshoot-a-wordpress-internal-server-error-27207#:%7E:text=Troubleshooting%20steps%3A,that%20hosts%20your%20WordPress%20website.&text=If%20the%20error%20is%20gone,will%20recreate%20your%20control%20file.)

[Fix GoDaddy Internal Server Error on WordPress](https://techdator.net/godaddy-internal-server-error/)

[500 error on GoDaddy hosting](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/500-error-on-godaddy-hosting/)

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: When I use GoDaddy with wordpress, I face this error and resolve this issue using these references. These are helpful because this kind of problem has many factors that why this is happening. So, I add all the possible solutions that I use back then.